# Querying database in real time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am retrieving some data from a database having a specific date and hour. Supposing I would like to see the data in real time.

Is there a way to automatically extract the data  without specifying the exact data and time?

Here is my query:

```
select   
    store,
    Count(bananas)
from
    database_name 
where   
    Date_hour between '2017-04-06 07:00:00' and '2017-04-07 07:00:02'
Group by 
    sore
```

Comment: How is the database supposed to know what to do if you don't give it parameters such as date and time?

Comment: what do you mean by "real time"

Comment: Seems you just looking for [Now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) - see Y.B.'s answer for how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select data for the last hour:

```
SELECT   store,
         Count(bananas)
FROM     table_name 
WHERE    date_hour > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY store
```